# Tensorflow, CNN + LSTM: Easier way to reuse CNN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, lstm

I am using `TensorFlow 1.15` to train an **LSTM** on **2D** images sequentially in time.  So effectively I have the following `[Input (3x) -> CNN -> LSTM -> Output]`.  Since I am training on multiple images, I want to apply the entire **`CNN`** subgraph to each image (*I would like to reuse all the weights since the current frame is image-wise no different from 1-X frame(s) ago*), then feed all the outputs to the LSTM.

My current code I am using 3 frames of data so I use a loop to create 3 placeholders (`Input0/Input1/Input2`) and 3 CNNs (sharing the weights by calling tf.Variable outside the loop, although tf.get_variable might simplify that a bit).

Is there a simpler way to express in TensorFlow I have a subgraph I want to call '`CNN`' and use it with X placeholders, then feed all those outputs to something like LSTM?

[image: Tensorboard]